# Printing to screen n Strings

Tags: c, printing, avl-tree

So basically I've an AVL tree filled with arrays of char's, and I know how to print all the arrays using recursive function print_inorder. What I want to do now is to print those arrays with a function that receives an int telling how many arrays to print at a time, and then expecting some action from the user to continue printing more arrays.

```
void print_inorder(pointer* p)
{
    if (p!=NULL)
    {
        print_inorder(p->left);
        printf("%s\n",p->name);
        print_inorder(p->right);
    }
}
```

This is my function to print btw. What I was thinking to do was to create a linked list and then loop through it, but I'm certain that's not the best way to do this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is the `pointer` type defined ?

Comment: Creating a linked list sounds good to me. You'd actually have another function similar to `print_inorder` but instead of the `printf("%s\n",p->name)` you would have something like `AddToList(thelist, p)`.

Comment: It's just a pointer to a struct... I put the * but the reality is that I defined a pointer to a avl tree, so it's really like (avl_pointer p)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to print ten strings ?

You should try something like this :

```
       int print_inorder(pointer* p, int nb)
       {
           if (p!=NULL)
           {
               nb = print_inorder(p->left,nb);
               if (nb >=0){
                    nb --;
                    printf("%s\n",p->name);
               }
               nb = print_inorder(p->right,nb);
           }
            return nb;
       }
```